# React native - Sending data to database from app in actual device not working

Tags: react-native

How do I send data to server in react native?

It is not doing that it's supposed to do. Instead of sending the data it just duplicates in my app.

Here is my send data code:

```
sendButtonClicked(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then(val => {
          fetch(`http://aaaa.000webhostapp.com/api/createPlate/${val}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    p_number: this.state.letters + ' ' + this.state.numbers
                })
            }).then(response => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
            })
        }).done()
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it just duplicate in my app'?

Comment: i got it working. My problem now is in the emulator it is working but when i use an actual device it doesnt send any data to the db

Comment: Does your phone have internet on?

Comment: Yes, i dont know why it doesnt send data with the phone

Comment: If you are using iOS, you have to add an exception for http://aaaa.000webhostapp.com, as it does not use HTTPS: http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/